# PDF::API2 can't write to page 2

Tags: perl, pdf

I have 2 .pdf files. Both are 1 page. I use them as watermark for invoices. Once page 1 (the 1st pdf) is filled I then like to import page 2 (the 2nd pdf) after page 1 and write to it. Obviously if it page 1 is not filled carry on writing to it. Here is a test code I have written:

```
my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();
my $sec_page = PDF::API2->open('./useful_scripts/invoice_page_2.pdf');
$pdf = PDF::API2->open('./useful_scripts/invoice.pdf');
my $page = $pdf->openpage(1);

my $text = $page->text();
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica-Bold');
$text->fillcolor('black');
$text->font($font, 11);

$text->translate(170, 785);
$text->text($invoice->ott_invoice_number);

my ( $y, $d, $x ) = ( 718, 15, 57 );

foreach my $line ( @{ $invoice->invoice_lines } ) {

    $text->translate( $x, $y );
    my $product = join( ': ', @{ $line->{display} } );
    $text->text($product);
    $y = $y - 13;

    if ( $line->{options} ) {

        foreach my $option ( @{ $line->{options} } ) {
            $text->translate( $x + 10, $y );
            $text->text($option);
        }

    }


}

$y = 100; #This is for testing purposes                                
          #so that I can make sure it is                               
          #writing to page 2                                           

if( $y < 150 ){
  $page = $pdf->importpage($sec_page);
  $page = $pdf->openpage(2);
  $text = $page->text();
  $text->translate(100,200);
  $text->text('Some test text...'); #This is LINE 59
}


#END                                                                   
$pdf->saveas('./test.pdf');
say 'Printing done... ;)';
```

However on line 59 (I have commented as line 59) I get an error saying:

```
Can't call method "isvirtual" on an undefined value at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/PDF/API2/Content.pm line 1558.
```

I have read similar questions with similar issues to myself and have tried the solutions that had been suggested. But none seem to work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the `$text` object for the second page, you need to call `$text->font(...)` again.  It doesn't carry over from the first page.

Add the following between line 57 and line 59:

```
$text->font($font, 11);
```

Comment: An answer from the module maintainer himself! Thanks a lot mate. Works fine now.

Comment: You're welcome!  To help people who run into this problem in the future (myself not least), I've also just made a release (2.022) that includes a more informative error message.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to initially have some default parameters for a new document, and carry newly set attributes over to new pages automatically? Or is that beyond the scope of this library? (Since the PDF format does not allow this either.)